# findAndModify documents with same value in array of nested documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

The starting point is a collection that looks like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55b3c75d84251af91782ea07"),
    "arr" : [
        {
            "val" : "yes"
        },
        {
            "val" : "yes"
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55b3c76184251af91782ea08"),
    "arr" : [
        {
            "val" : "yes"
        },
        {
            "val" : "no"
        }
    ]
}
...
```

What I want to find are documents that only have `yes`'s in `arr.val`. Please note that you will need to use `findAndModify` because I will need to update the documents afterwards.

What I've tried:

```
> db.coll.find({arr: {$all: [{$elemMatch: {val: 'yes'}}]}})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55b3c75d84251af91782ea07"), "arr" : [ { "val" : "yes" }, { "val" : "yes" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55b3c76184251af91782ea08"), "arr" : [ { "val" : "yes" }, { "val" : "no" } ] }
> db.coll.find({arr: {$all: [{val: 'yes'}]}})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55b3c75d84251af91782ea07"), "arr" : [ { "val" : "yes" }, { "val" : "yes" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55b3c76184251af91782ea08"), "arr" : [ { "val" : "yes" }, { "val" : "no" } ] }
```

Both versions still find both documents.

Comment: Your scenario is a little unclear. What sort of update are you doing? You can use `update` to update all documents that match `val: 'yes'` in an element, unless you need to do updating beyond the capabilities of `update`. Otherwise, you probably just want to use `find` and update them after that. Anyway, you should add the type of update you're planning on doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using a combination of `$eq` and `$ne` to find docs that contain at least one `arr` element where `val` is `'yes'`, and no elements where its value is `'no'`:

```javascript
db.coll.find({"arr.val": {$eq: 'yes', $ne: 'no'}})
```

Matches just the first doc:

```javascript
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55b3c75d84251af91782ea07"),
    "arr" : [
        {
            "val" : "yes"
        },
        {
            "val" : "yes"
        }
    ]
}
```

In a `findAndModify`:

```javascript
db.coll.findAndModify({
    query: {"arr.val": {$eq: 'yes', $ne: 'no'}}, 
    update: {$set: {a: 1}}, 
    new: true
})
```